# Raster calculator: IF (A-B=A) THEN classify

Tags: raster, qgis

Without using any Python (i.e. only thru QGIS interface and its raster calculators), is there a way to perform and evaluation of a subtraction to be equal to one of the input rasters and, if true, reclassify those cells as an integer?

For example:

```
IF (raster_A@1 - raster_B@1 = raster_A@1, 99, NoData)
```

Into words: given a raster, I would like to check the presence of the cells of one raster over another (I guess thru their difference), and if the raster is present (raster_A@1) and the other one isn't (raster_B@1), reclassify the former raster to a unique value for all cells, otherwise NoData. I have tried doing the following using the core raster calculator:

```
(raster_A@1 - raster_B@1 = raster_A@1)*99
```

or

```
((raster_A@1 - raster_B@1) = raster_A@1)*99
```

and obviously two logics in the same instruction

```
((raster_A@1 - raster_B@1) = raster_A@1)*99 + ((raster_B@1 - raster_A@1) = raster_B@1)*-99
```

But my logic is faulty: it returns a raster which histogram shows only 0 to 0

Comment: This would get more traction at gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

first verify if that raster data is of same type, like both 0-255 or 0.0-1.0